# angular 8 unit test with jest for http post catchError

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, ts-jest

Hello i would like unit test cover catchError branch for the http post:

```
 getSession() {
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-API-Version': 'resource=2.0'
      }
    };
    return this.http.post(SESSION_REST_API_URL, '', options as any)
      .pipe(
        timeoutWith(10000, throwError(new Error('exceeded'))),
        catchError((error: any) => throwError(error))
      );
  }
```

in my test 'it', i tried to listen `toHaveReturnedWith` and `toEqual` in subscribe  this post but not covered:

```
it('should throwError', () => {
  // arrange
  const error = throwError({error: 400});
  const options = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',, 'Accept-API-Version': 'resource=2.0'}}
  ;
  UtilsTest.mockReturnValue(service['http'], 'post', throwError(error));
  // act
  service.getSession();
  // assert 1
  expect(service['http'].post(SESSION_REST_API_URL, '', options)).toHaveReturnedWith(of({error: 400}));
  // assert 2
  expect(loginCredentialsService.getSessionJsonResponse()).toHaveReturnedWith(error)
  // assert 3
  service['http'].post(SESSION_REST_API_URL, '', options).subscribe({
    error: (err) => {
      expect(err).toEqual({error: 400});
    }
  });
});
```

some id to achieve that ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear but seems like you need to wait until subscribers fire. You can use Marble testing (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing) for that. Or if it is simple u can use done like below

Hello i would like unit test cover catchError branch for the http post:

```
it('should throwError', (done) => {
  .....
  service['http'].post(SESSION_REST_API_URL, '', options).subscribe({
    error: (err) => {
      expect(err).toEqual({error: 400});
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I try just to cover the code in red, and expect(err).toEqual({error: 400}) already tried.